# Android how to block accessing specified URLs ?

Tags: android-intent, service, filter

I need to create an application which should work behind and checks the url entered to the browser. Ex : lets say url : www.youtube.com app needs to tell user that s/he cant visit that site. I mean I need a web filter in short.

It tried broadcastreceiver but I coudnt do that. I tried to edit host and did it but thats not the app that I really want. Because I want to connect to my app by web service and send some urls to my app and those will be blocked. I tried to reach the text written to web browser and if its on my black list url I stoped the webbrowser but again thats not the thing that I want.

Can you please suggest me how can I implement this app ? Thanks guys.